# Small C++ code irritating my mind

Tags: c++, arrays

please consider this short C++ code

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    clrscr();
    char arr[]="MQMHSJKLSUGDUGIGIUDKLKO";
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
       if(i%2==0)
       {
           cout<<arr[i];
       }
    }

    char a[]={'78','45','21','5'};
    cout<<(int)a;
    getch();
}
```

the output is 'MMS 18'

MMS is clear from the first loop, but how '18' is the output of second one ?
even if you change the array elements, the answer remains 18. 
Please explain !

Comment: It might well change each time you run the code. Because you are printing the address for the first element of the array, by typecasting to int

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`a` converted to a pointer to its first element. You are trying to print the address of first element by casting it to `int`. Result may vary compiler to compiler.

Answer (score 0):

'a' represent the address of the first element in the array.
As if in your code the address of the first element of the array 'a' is 18.If you try *a instead of a it would give you the answer as 78.The code you expect could be

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    clrscr();
    char arr[]="MQMHSJKLSUGDUGIGIUDKLKO";
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        if(i%2==0)
        {
           cout<<arr[i];
        }
    }

    char a[]={'78','45','21','5'};
    cout<<(*a);
    getch();
}
```